# ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'codeSprint' of undefined at Object.eval [as updateRenderer] using Angular

Tags: angular, error-handling

Could someone explain what might have went wrong ? I am getting this error

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'codeSprint' of undefined
    at Object.eval [as updateRenderer] (SprintComponent.html:12)
    at Object.debugUpdateRenderer [as updateRenderer] (core.js:45294)
    at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:44277)
```

in SprintComponent.html :

```
<div ngFor="let sprint of sprints">
    {{sprint.codeSprint}}
    {{sprint.title}}
  </div>
```

in SprintComponent.ts:

```
sprints : Sprint[];
```

in SprintService.ts:

```
getSprints(): Observable<Sprint[]> {
    const token = localStorage.getItem('kno');
    const rqwstrId = localStorage.getItem('rqwstrId');
    let header = new HttpHeaders('Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8'); 
    header = header.append('kno',token);
    header = header.append('rqwstrId', rqwstrId);
    let param = new HttpParams().set('code',"Koon52");
    return this.http.get<Sprint[]>(this.baseUrl + '/v1/sprints/', {headers : header , params : param});
  }
```

with Sprint as an class with following properties:

```
export class Sprint {
  kno:string;
  rqwstrId : string;
  code: string;
  codeSprint : string;
  dateDebut : string;
  dateFin : string;
  title : string;

  constructor() {
  }
}
```

meanwhile when i log it in the console, it displays the data like this:

```
SprintComponent.html:9 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'codeSprint' of undefined
    at Object.eval [as updateRenderer] (SprintComponent.html:9)
    at Object.debugUpdateRenderer [as updateRenderer] (core.js:45294)
    at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:44277)
    at callViewAction (core.js:44637)
    at execComponentViewsAction (core.js:44565)
    at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:44278)
    at callViewAction (core.js:44637)
    at execEmbeddedViewsAction (core.js:44594)
    at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:44272)
    at callViewAction (core.js:44637)
```

I call getSprints method in SprintComponent like this :

```
ngOnInit() : void {
    this.sprintService.getSprints().subscribe(
      data =>
      {
          this.sprints = data;
      }
    );
```

And Thanks!

Comment: I tried *ngFor but it doesn't work

Comment: how did you call the getSprints function in SprintComponent.ts? and use *ngFor.

Comment: @polyglot like this: ngOnInit() : void {
    this.sprintService.getSprints().subscribe(
      data =>
      {
          this.sprints = data;
      }
    );

Comment: can you put `console.log(data)` before `this.sprints = data` line for testing purpose?

Comment: @polyglot Where can I see the result of this console and Thank you so much

Comment: tap F12 key then you can see browser dev tool opened at the right side of browser. clicking the Console tab will show you what you logged with console.log

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221901/discussion-between-polyglot-and-sarah).

Comment: @polyglot the same error and other errors like this : Uncaught ReferenceError: df3 is not defined
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (app.js:9)

Answer (score 0):

You need to subscribe the methode in your component

```
sprints:any[]=[];
 in your ngoninit 

     this.service.getSprints().subscribe((response) => {
            this.sprints=response as any 
            });
    
    )}
```

in your component.html

```
<div *ngFor="let sprint of sprintd">
 {{sprint.codeSprint}}
    {{sprint.title}}
</div>
```

Comment: The same problem

Comment: i think you forgot the * in the ngFor      it should be like this *ngFor="let sprint of sprints"

Comment: I got these errors: ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of null
    at HttpHeaders.applyUpdate (http.js:332)
and : 
Uncaught ReferenceError: df3 is not defined
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (app.js:9)

Comment: yep, and it returns some sprints